# Как упростить связывание кнопки и функции-обработчика события в Tkinter, Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Вот работающий код небольшой программки  с использованием библиотеки Tkinter. В ней для каждой кнопки приходится писать свою функцию-обработчик события, а затем связывать эту функцию с самой кнопкой. Порядка 70% строк кода посвящено именно этому.

Я уверен, что процедуру можно серьезно упростить (как, например, у меня получилось упростить создание самих кнопок), потому что построены они по одному и тому же принципу. К сожалению, видимо, сейчас моих знаний недостаточно, чтобы самостоятельно справиться с этой задачей. Подскажите, как можно упростить этот код?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root["bg"] = "red"
root.geometry("+1+6")

buts = {}
fras = {}
chngs = {}
sizes = ("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL")


def chng1(event):
    for f in fras:
        fras[f].configure(width=30, height=30)
    for b in buts:
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", 10))
        buts[b].place(width=20, height=20)


def chng2(event):
    for f in fras:
        fras[f].configure(width=60, height=60)
    for b in buts:
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", 11))
        buts[b].place(width=40, height=40)


def chng3(event):
    for f in fras:
        fras[f].configure(width=90, height=90)
    for b in buts:
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", 14))
        buts[b].place(width=60, height=60)


def chng4(event):
    for f in fras:
        fras[f].configure(width=120, height=120)
    for b in buts:
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", 19))
        buts[b].place(width=80, height=80)


def chng5(event):
    for f in fras:
        fras[f].configure(width=150, height=150)
    for b in buts:
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", 26))
        buts[b].place(width=100, height=100)


def chng6(event):
    for f in fras:
        fras[f].configure(width=180, height=180)
    for b in buts:
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", 35))
        buts[b].place(width=120, height=120)


def back(event):
    for k in range(6):
        b = "but_{}".format(sizes[k])
        f = "fra_{}".format(k + 1)

        fras[f].configure(width=30*(k+1),
                          height=30*(k+1))
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", 10+int(k**2)))
        buts[b].place(width=20*(k+1),
                      height=20*(k+1))


fra_main = Frame(root,
                 bg="blue")
fra_main.grid(row=0,
              column=0,
              columnspan=3)

for i in range(6):
    but = "but_{}".format(sizes[i])
    fra = "fra_{}".format(i + 1)
    fras[fra] = Frame(fra_main,
                      bg="yellow",
                      borderwidth=3,
                      width=30 * (i + 1),
                      height=30 * (i + 1))
    buts[but] = Button(fras[fra],
                       text="{}".format(sizes[i]),
                       font=("Impact", (10 + int(i ** 2))),
                       bg="bisque",
                       padx=10,
                       pady=10)
    fras[fra].pack(side=LEFT,
                   padx=10,
                   pady=10)
    buts[but].place(width=20 * (i + 1),
                    height=20 * (i + 1),
                    anchor=CENTER,
                    relx=0.5,
                    rely=0.5)

buts["but_XS"].bind("<Button-1>", chng1)
buts["but_S"].bind("<Button-1>", chng2)
buts["but_M"].bind("<Button-1>", chng3)
buts["but_L"].bind("<Button-1>", chng4)
buts["but_XL"].bind("<Button-1>", chng5)
buts["but_XXL"].bind("<Button-1>", chng6)

back_but = Button(root,
                  text="Back to demo",
                  padx=20,
                  pady=20)

back_but.bind("<Button-1>", back)
back_but.grid(row=1,
              column=1,
              padx=10,
              pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо всех ваших функций можно заменить

```
def func(size_flag, size_font, size_but):
    for f in fras:
        fras[f].configure(width=size_flag, height=size_flag)
    for b in buts:
        buts[b].configure(font=("Impact", size_font))
        buts[b].place(width=size_but, height=size_but)
```

а сам вызов при нажатии заменить на

```
buts["but_XS"].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: func(30, 10, 20))
buts["but_S"].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: func(60, 11, 40))
buts["but_M"].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: func(90, 14, 60))
buts["but_L"].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: func(120, 19, 80))
buts["but_XL"].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: func(150, 26, 100))
buts["but_XXL"].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: func(180, 36, 120))
```